# Count check after a certain date using rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am trying add an additional check on the issues that only those issues are selected for which there is no transaction record after the last reminder. Please help me how can I do that.

```
Office.all.each do |office|
    transaction_ids = []
    office.issues.where("issues.account > 1").each do |issue|
      transaction = issue.transactions.where(type: :paid).order(:date).last
      transaction_ids << transaction.id if transaction.date < Reminder.last.date
    end
    Worker.perform_async(transaction_ids) if transaction_ids.any?
end
```

Update

I was thinking of something like this but it doesn't work because I am getting this error **PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "last"**

```
office.issues.where("issues.account > 1").joins(:transactions).where(transactions.last.date < Reminder.last.date).each do |issue|
```

Comment: Can you explain what currently isn't working?

Comment: @SyntacticFructose This query is working perfectly fine. But I am not able to figure out how can I add an additional condition so that only those issues are selected that don't have transactions after the reminder date and account greater than 1(which I already have).

Comment: `office.issues.joins(:transactions).where('issues.account > 1').group(:id).having('max(transactions.date) > max(reminders.date)')` would something like that work?